Remove premium features from bundle for unregistered users in NextJS
I have a NextJS app and I want to make some features available only for the premium users.
I have a method to determine if the user is premium.
Now I want to do the following:
in a method on the server (so that users cannot tamper with it - to clarify - it's a purely frontend app, no backend here.) I want to check if the user is premium and Lazy import the premium component:
if (isPremium) {
    // Dynamically import premium feature
    const { PremiumComponent } = await import("../app/engine/PremiumComponent");
    return PremiumComponent;
}

return undefined;

PremiumCopmponent is a normal React component. I just don't want to include it in the bundle for non-premium users
Then I want to send this to the client component which would either render this component if there server returned it.
However, NextJS throws different errors:
[If I try to return the component as in example above]

Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you
explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". Or maybe you
meant to call this function rather than return it.

[If I try to return some JS functionality]

Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client
Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not
supported.

Please suggest if this is legit apporach at all or how to do that alternatively
